# How to work with stripe.js in an Ionic/Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I am working on an app (**`ionic/angular`**) and now need to include payment via credit card using `Stripe`.

After much research on the internet I decided to use **`Stripe.js`** (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js).

In the `index.html` of the project, I made the inclusion of `Stripe.js` and it looks like this:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I now import Stripe into **`app/app.module.ts`** to use `Stripe` on another page (Example: in `pages/payment/payment.page.ts`)?

Comment: Hey did you try any guidances like this one? https://baadiersydow.com/integrate-ionic-framework-stripe-single-recurring-payments/ then if you faced a particular issue - you could ask specific question

Comment: Helped me a lot ... thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `npm install ngx-stripe`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import your library
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot('***your-stripe-publishable key***'),
    LibraryModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Read more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe)

Comment: When I wrote the question, after searching, I need to use `<script src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/">`. Do you know how to import? Thank you

Comment: @MarceloAndradeAmadeu Actually, I don't think that it 's a good idea to implement stripe on front-end side

Answer (score 3):

no need to import in `app/app.module.ts`,

in `pages/payment/payment.page.ts`;u need `declare let Stripe`

Comment: Perfect ... it was much simpler than I'd imagined. That was all I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Adding to this you might check out @types/stripe (there's a couple ) so that it might help you with intellisense if using VS Code.